# Draw part of ring with non-zero thickness using PSTricks

Tags: pstricks

Is there a command for drawing part of a ring with non-zero thickness using PSTricks?

I know of `\psRing` but this draws a full ring.

What I want is similar to `\pswedge` but without the part of the wedge closest to the 'center'.

**Update**

Here is what I have 'brewed up' myself:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\def\ringSegment(#1,#2)#3#4#5#6{%
  \psline(!#3 #5 cos mul #1 add #3 #5 sin mul #2 add)(!#4 #5 cos mul #1 add #4 #5 sin mul #2 add)
  \psarc(#1,#2){#4}{#5}{#6}
  \psline(!#4 #6 cos mul #1 add #4 #6 sin mul #2 add)(!#3 #6 cos mul #1 add #3 #6 sin mul #2 add)
  \psarc(#1,#2){#3}{#5}{#6}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](0,0)(3,3)
  \ringSegment(-0.2,-0.2){2}{3}{30}{60}
  \pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue]{\ringSegment(-0.2,-0.2){2}{3}{30}{60}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

It is almost as I want it but the filling is not correct; the inner-most part of the filling is alone a line segment instead of along an arc. Can anyone help me fix this?

**Update 2**

I got it now; the enclosed area needs to be drawn clockwise instead of anti-clockwise:

```
\def\ringSegment(#1,#2)#3#4#5#6{%
  \psarc(#1,#2){#3}{#5}{#6}
  \psline(!#3 #6 cos mul #1 add #3 #6 sin mul #2 add)(!#4 #6 cos mul #1 add #4 #6 sin mul #2 add)
  \psarc(#1,#2){#4}{#5}{#6}
  \psline(!#4 #5 cos mul #1 add #4 #5 sin mul #2 add)(!#3 #5 cos mul #1 add #3 #5 sin mul #2 add)
}
```

Comment: `\psRing` is defined in [pst-news13](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/base/doc/pst-news13.pdf).

Comment: @Werner Exactly. `:)` It is in `pstricks-add`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\makeatletter
\def\ringSegment{\pst@object{ringSegment}}
\def\ringSegment@i(#1)#2#3#4#5{%
  \begin@ClosedObj
  \use@par
  \pscustom{%
    \psarc(#1){#3}{#4}{#5}% Upper arc
    \psarcn(#1){#2}{#5}{#4}% Lower arc
    \closepath
  }\end@ClosedObj\ignorespaces}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](0,0)(3,3)
  \ringSegment(-0.5,-0.2){2}{3}{30}{60}
  \ringSegment*[linecolor=blue](-0.2,-0.2){2}{3}{30}{60}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

or with the current `pstricks-add.tex` version from http://texnik.dante.de/tex/generic/pstricks-add/.

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-3,-3)(3,3)
\psRing(0,0)[30,60]{2}{3}
\psRing*[linecolor=red,opacity=0.4](0,0)[60,30]{2}{3}
\psRing[linecolor=blue](0,0)[200,250]{2}{3}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You need to trace the bottom part of `\ringSegment` using `\psarcn` rather than `\psarc`. Below I've updated the `\ringSegment` macro to take an optional argument as well:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}% http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi/

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ringSegment}[1][]{
  \expandafter\ringSegment@\expandafter[#1]}
\def\ringSegment@[#1](#2,#3)#4#5#6#7{%
  \pscustom[#1]{%
    \psline(!#4 #6 cos mul #2 add #4 #6 sin mul #3 add)(!#5 #6 cos mul #2 add #5 #6 sin mul #3 add)% Left edge
    \psarc(#2,#3){#5}{#6}{#7}% Upper arc
    \psline(!#5 #7 cos mul #2 add #5 #7 sin mul #3 add)(!#4 #7 cos mul #2 add #4 #7 sin mul #3 add)% Right edge
    \psarcn(#2,#3){#4}{#7}{#6}% Lower arc
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](0,0)(3,3)
  \ringSegment(-0.5,-0.2){2}{3}{30}{60}
  \ringSegment[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue](-0.2,-0.2){2}{3}{30}{60}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Use `\psarc` for anti-clockwise and `\psarcn` for clockwise oriented arcs. The notation is similar for both. See the [`pstricks` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/base/doc/pstricks-doc.pdf) for more (section **7 Arcs, circles and ellipses**).

You may also be interested in the pair `\psellipticarc` and `\psellipticarcn`.

<sup>You may also consider drawing a super-thick line segment using `\psarc`/`\psarcn`...</sup>

Answer (score 5):

A recommended solution only for the best practitioners. The simplification not only makes the code much more readable but it also saves more keystrokes, which in turn, reduces the carbon emission.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ringSegment}[1][]{
  \expandafter\ringSegment@\expandafter[#1]}
  \def\ringSegment@[#1](#2,#3)#4#5#6#7{%
  \rput(#2,#3){%
  \pscustom[#1]{%
    \psarc(0,0){#5}{#6}{#7}% Upper arc
    \psarcn(0,0){#4}{#7}{#6}% Lower arc
    \closepath
  }}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](0,0)(3,3)
  \ringSegment(-0.5,-0.2){2}{3}{30}{60}
  \ringSegment[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue](-0.2,-0.2){2}{3}{30}{60}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another version for Herbert's solution.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}

\makeatletter
\def\ringSegment{\pst@object{ringSegment}}
\def\ringSegment@i(#1)#2#3#4#5{{%
  \use@par
  \pscustom[origin={#1}]{%
    \psarc(0,0){#3}{#4}{#5}% Upper arc
    \psarcn(0,0){#2}{#5}{#4}% Lower arc
    \closepath
  }}\ignorespaces}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](0,0)(3,3)
  \ringSegment(-0.5,-0.2){2}{3}{30}{60}
  \ringSegment[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue](-0.2,-0.2){2}{3}{30}{60}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Its output is the same!

### Notes:

`\psarc` and `\psarcn` seem to be inconsistent with other graphic objects because `(0,0)` cannot be ignored for both of them.

If you insist on ignoring the origin, use the following.

```
\psellipticarc(#3,#3){#4}{#5}% Upper arc
\psellipticarcn(#2,#2){#5}{#4}% Lower arc
```